# How to secure a fully carbon (aero) bike when washing/repairing on a stand?

Tags: carbon, cleaning, racing-bikes

My bike is fully carbon (frame, seatpost, saddle etc...) and I clean it regularly. I have read/heard from multiple sources that you should not clamp carbon materials when using a bike stand. However, without clamping, the bike slides everywhere. In particular when I rest the bike on the bottom set of clamp teeth during a cleaning session. The bike is fully aero and I'm very conscious about clamping it too tightly.

I have seen [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7615/carbon-seatpost-frame-in-repair-stand) post relating to bike stands and carbon frames but it doesn't help me. I'm want to know how people with all-carbon aero bikes secure them when cleaning?

1) Are there any special clamps/stands out there that are made specifically to secure carbon bikes?

2) Has anyone got any home-made solutions to secure their carbon aero frames/seatposts?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an appropriate question for a Q&A site like this. It's likely to generate opinions rather than answers. Nonetheless, here's one approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ei8Kt2bfEE

Comment: Cheers for the video link. I've never seen a stand like that. Going to see if I can find one.     Also, blasting with  a pressure washer that close.... not in a million years

Comment: Question seems straightforward and objective: Can I clamp a CF seatpost in a bike repair stand? Are there products that make it possible/safer?

Comment: @JamesPeterMcConnell [GCN did a test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzbpHGyFzc8) and found it's actually pretty difficult to get water into bearings with a pressure washer. Their test wasn't entirely realistic but they didn't get any water in a bottom bracket bearing after pressure washing it for a minute and a half at close range. But your concern is completely rational.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The seatpost is a fairly sturdy carbon tube, as it has to withstand the mass of the rider on one and of it and some significant bending forces.

Also, the seatpost has to be clamped by the frame, so it can take some clamping force.

For cleaning, you should not have to clamp the seatpost particularly hard, just enough to support the bike.

I note that Simon Richardson of GCN clamps a Ridley bike on its carbon seatpost [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ak4AzlUz5Q).

Comment: Very minor niggle - that's his OWN bike, not a demo bike or a show bike.

Comment: Actually it's co-presenter [Tom Last's personal bike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCkYeNaGNW0), but your point is a good one. It's a bike they care about.

Comment: And bike seatposts are a lot cheaper to replace than a whole frame.

Comment: @Criggie seatpost need to be incredibly strong and resilient. If clamping a seat post in a bike stand damages the carbon structure that thing was about to fail on you under normal riding and you should be thankful that you found out in the bike stand rather than on the road.

Answer (score 6):

I find for cleaning, no need to clamp the seat post, tighten the clamp so its captured the seat post, but leave it loose and let the bike slide down and hang off the seat. If you want clamp a little to stop the bike swinging in the breeze, or just set the height so a wheel touches the ground.